# Placing command-line arguments properly onto stack

Tags: assembly, command-line, x86, stack

Forgive me if my terminology isn't correct.

I'm trying to implement an x86 gnu c based system and it's ability to pass command-line arguments to a program. Not to be confused with accessing them within the program, but in fact setting up the stack before passing execution onto the user program.

From what I'v gathered argc and argv are pushed into the stack but it is that construction process that I'm missing something in. Below is how I'm executing another program.

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("pushl %%ds\n" /* save data and extra segment registers */
        "pushl %%es\n" 
        "movl %%esp, %%ebx\n" 
        "movl %%ebx, oldsp\n" 
        "movl %%ss, %%ebx\n" 
        "movl %%ebx, oldss\n" 
        "movl %0, %%ds\n"   /* set data segment to new user base */

        "movl %0, %%ss\n" 
        "movl $0xfff0, %%ebx\n" /* start of the new user stack pointer */
        "movl %%ebx, %%esp\n"
        "movl %2, %%eax\n"  /* place i into eax - push it onto the stack*/
        "pushl %%eax\n"
        "pushl %%eax\n"
        "lcallw  *%%fs:(%1)\n" 
        "movl %%fs:oldss, %%ebx\n" 
        "movl %%ebx, %%ss\n" 
        "movl %%fs:oldsp, %%ebx\n" 
        "movl %%ebx, %%esp\n" 
        "popl  %%es\n"  /* restore old segment registers */
        "popl  %%ds\n"
        :
        :"a" (userbase), "d" (&useg), "r" (i)
        :"%ebx", "eax", "memory");  /* prevents gcc from optimizing useg away*/
```

I was under the impression that I could push values onto the stack after the stack pointer was updated. I'm clearly not getting the values I'v pushed onto the stack, so I'm not even really sure if I'm even going about it the right way.

Below is a simply test program that was trying to read argc print to the screen.

```
.file    "prog3.c"
#APP
.code16gcc

call main

lretw

.section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
.string    "\r\nstring: %u"
#NO_APP
.section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.globl    main
.type    main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
pushl    %ebp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
.cfi_offset 5, -8
movl    %esp, %ebp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 5
andl    $-16, %esp
subl    $16, %esp
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
call    printf
leave
.cfi_restore 5
.cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
.size    main, .-main
.ident    "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I've looked at how the stack is prepared for function calls thinking it could be a similar process, but I'm still at a disconnect.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Progress: I think I may have found a crude work around. I completely removed argc and argv from the main declaration. For two reasons, 1. I'll just populate my own variables for the time being and two, there may be other things missing in my pet OS that gcc assumes when compiling for these test programs to work.
Right now I manually grabbed the value off the stack from some inline assembly that wasn't hard. Would still like to get this working properly though.
addl $4, %esp # parameter on stack; movl (%esp), %eax # move to next

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the stack when the program tries to read its argument, and how everything got there:

```
mov    %ebx, %esp # 0xfff0
push   %eax       # 0xffec i
push   %eax       # 0xffe8 i
lcallw *%fs:useg  # 0xffe4 return address 1
call   main       # 0xffe0 return address 2
push   %ebp       # 0xffdc old ebp
mov    %esp, %ebp # ebp = 0xffdc
```

GCC expects function arguments to be placed just above the return address on the stack. This means that the first argument should be at `ebp + 8`. You can see here, however, that the value at that location is the return address from the `lcallw` instruction, so that is what the main function will see as its first argument. In order to get the arguments you placed there, you need to either have the user code that calls `main` (let's call it `start`) copy it between the two return addresses, or not change the size of the stack at all in that code.

Since the length of the arguments on the stack is currently constant, and small, it isn't difficult for `start` to simply copy the data. You just need to re-push the two values, so `start` would look like this:

```
push   8(%esp) # Copy the high value
push   8(%esp) # Copy the low value
call   main
add    $8,%esp
lretw
```

For longer or non-constant arguments, this is slower because you have to both determine how much to copy, and copy all of it.

You can do this without copying if `start` does not change the size of the stack before calling `main`. Since it needs to place its own return address on the stack, this means it needs to move the other return address somewhere else. The best way to do this is to have your system assume that one of the registers which is normally preserved is not, so that `start` can store the return address there. It looks like you aren't using `ebp`, `esi`, or `edi` for anything in the code that runs the program, so you could use any of them by simply adding it to the list of destroyed registers in the inline-assembly, then change your `start` to store the first return address there.

```
pop    %esi  # Pop first return address
call   main
push   %esi  # Restore first return address
lretw
```